# For Entity Framework associations, are Independent Associations or FK Associations recommended?

Tags: entity-framework, data-modeling, entity-framework-4, modeling

For Entity Framework associations, are Independent Associations or FK Associations recommended?

I have been receiving an error with the multiplicity I tried to use in an independent association.

Answer (score 0):

The errors I was receiving were fixed when I re-ran the "Generate Database from Model" command. I must re-run this every model change I make to clear the errors.

I will use the FK Associations since they are currently the default.